# Apex Scheduler doesn't work properly

Tags: apex, scheduled-apex, scheduled-job

I have a apex scheduler to check lead that work every 15 minutes. It only works on first action/scheduled job. I am not sure if i create that based on salesforce base practice but when i try my code (execute anonymous window developer console), it works as expected. Is there a way to check scheduler if it working or not?

Here is my apex scheduler code.

```
global class CallQueueLeadChecker implements Schedulable {
Datetime dtNow = system.now();

global void execute(SchedulableContext SC){
checkLead();
}

public void checkLead(){
    List<Lead> leadList = [SELECT Id,Active_Call_Queue2__c  FROM Lead WHERE Active_Call_Queue2__c = FALSE AND No_Call_Queue__c = FALSE AND (NOT Phone LIKE '%wrong%') AND (NOT Phone LIKE '%invalid%') AND (NOT MobilePhone LIKE '%wrong%') AND (NOT MobilePhone LIKE '%invalid%') AND (Phone !=null OR MobilePhone !=null) AND (Status='Open' OR Status = 'Contacted') AND Picked_By__c=null AND Is_Picked__c = FALSE AND (Last_Open_Timestamp_Formula__c <: dtNow OR Last_Open_Timestamp_Formula__c = NULL) ORDER BY Hubspot_Score__c DESC NULLS LAST LIMIT 200];
    for(Lead l : leadList){
        l.Active_Call_Queue2__c = TRUE;
    }
    update leadList;
  }
}
```

And here is my cron jobs that i used to run every 15 minutes

```
System.schedule('Call Queue Checker 0', '0 0 * * * ?', new CallQueueLeadChecker());
System.schedule('Call Queue Checker 15', '0 15 * * * ?', new CallQueueLeadChecker());
System.schedule('Call Queue Checker 30', '0 30 * * * ?', new CallQueueLeadChecker());
System.schedule('Call Queue Checker 45', '0 45 * * * ?', new CallQueueLeadChecker());
```

Thanks

Comment: which cron expression are you using to schedule the job.  Also provide the code from which you are scheduling the above class.

Comment: In Setup enter "apex Jobs" to see when it executed and if it had any errors.

Comment: Hi @ManjotSingh, i have edit the post. kindly take a look on my cron jobs.

Comment: Hi @Basti, i just check the apex jobs as you suggested. All of my scheduled jobs are queued, it means working right?

Comment: your cron looks correct. If your jobs are in queue then they will execute. Schedule jobs don't run on time. they will run whenever resources are free.

Comment: Is there a way to check the current available resource?

Comment: Salesforce doesn't give any indication when it will schedule a job (if that is what you meant to say with "check current resource"). In this case, you need to ensure that run of a previous job is not running if concurrency is an issue.